# Systemd service fails with status=203/EXEC although shebang is in sh file

Tags: bash, raspberry-pi, systemd

I have a short bash script that I want to automatically start when my Raspberry Pi boots up. Using systemd, I've been trying to test the service file manually but it always enters a fail state, not sure what I'm doing wrong.

I've Googled around and most people say they solved their problem by adding 
`#!/bin/bash` to the top of their .sh file, or adding that path to the service file (i.e. `ExecStart=/bin/bash file_to_execute.service`). I've tried both of these and I'm still running into errors.

Here is my .sh file, I've confirmed that it works when I manually run it:

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo mining/2pac/cgminer/cgminer --default-config mining/2pac/cgminer/cgminer.conf &

sudo python3 mining/2pac/cgminer/BTCLotto-master/btclotto.py
```

Here is the service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=BTC Lotto Miner
After=network.target network-online.target
Wants=network-online.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/mining/2pac/cgminer/lottominer.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

With these files, these are the errors I get when I run the service with     `sudo systemctl start lottominer.service`:

```
lottominer.service - BTC Lotto Miner
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/lottominer.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2019-07-24 16:47:05 UTC; 2s ago
  Process: 2324 ExecStart=/mining/2pac/cgminer/lottominer.sh (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
 Main PID: 2324 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Jul 24 16:47:05 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started BTC Lotto Miner.
Jul 24 16:47:05 raspberrypi systemd[1]: lottominer.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Jul 24 16:47:05 raspberrypi systemd[1]: lottominer.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jul 24 16:47:05 raspberrypi systemd[1]: lottominer.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

When I edit the service file to `ExecStart=/bin/bash /mining/2pac/cgminer/lottominer.sh` and also maintain the shebang in the .sh file, I get the same errors but the error changes to `(code=exited, status=127)`

Any help is appreciated, I've been reading forums for a long time with no answers...

Comment: Uses absolute paths and no relative ones, like `mining/2pac/cgminer/cgminer`.